# Ejected Expo app (ExpoKit) does not work in offline mode on first boot

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I am facing a problem with an ejected Expo app. When I build an APK of my app with gradlew (yes, I have ran `react-native bundle` command before the build), the application still somehow tries to fetch OTA updates from Expo's server (published channel). Is there any solution, that the application would not try to fetch the published JS content from Expo? Because after the first boot with internet, the application is working even without internet.
Thanks in advance.